# dose model.fit() call model.predict() somewhere in Keras?

Tags: keras

I always assume `model.fit()` calls `model.predict()` somewhere because the loss function defined with the `y_true` and `y_pred` regarding the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py). However, I notice that `model.predict()` return an numpy array, and `y_pred` is a tensor. Isn't the y_pred from the predict function?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't call `model.predict()`.

You can check the source code, but it's rather long and complicated: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py

Comment: Thank you, I see. What if I need to use the result from model.predict() to define a loss function and than go back to fine-tune the LSTM. Can I only convert the y_pred to an array, then calculate a loss and finally convert back to a scalar tensor? Is there any easier or better approach? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Work only with the tensors `y_true` and `y_pred` inside the loss function. You can't transform it into an array. Use the backend functions: https://keras.io/backend/